# Aggregate initialization error in GCC 4.8.5

Tags: c++, gcc

I am trying to port (something similar to) the following code to RHEL 7:

```
enum class TestEnum {
  Foo,
  Bar,
};

struct TestStruct {
  TestStruct() = delete;
  bool test_bool;
  TestEnum test_enum;

  bool operator==(const TestStruct &other) const {
    return test_bool == other.test_bool &&
          test_enum == other.test_enum;
  }
  bool operator!=(const TestStruct &other) const {
    return !(*this == other);
  }
};

class TestClass {
private:
  TestStruct test_struct { false, TestEnum::Foo };
};
```

but it does not compile for me using GCC 4.8.5 on CentOS 7:

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44)

$ gcc --std=c++11 test_aggregate.cpp -o test_aggregate.o
test_aggregate.cpp:22:49: error: could not convert '{false, Foo}' from '<brace-enclosed initializer 
list>' to 'TestStruct'
   TestStruct test_struct { false, TestEnum::Foo };
                                             ^
```

As I understand it, this is [aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization), but I cannot see what in the rules should disallow this, and the same code compiles fine elsewhere using GCC 7.3.1.

What do I need to change in order to compile this with 4.8.5?

Comment: Looks like [gcc 4.8.5](https://godbolt.org/z/h75feP) didn't fully support this but [gcc 4.9.0](https://godbolt.org/z/78ahGr) does.  So you'll probably need to upgrade your compiler.

Comment: You might also try using `--std=gnu++1y` to see if this particular feature is included.  BTW, you can find g++ 8.3 in a repo suitable for RHEL, though I don't recall exactly where.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For compilers that don't support/allow this type of aggregate initialization<sup>†</sup> (due to the fact that your `TestStruct` class has a deleted default constructor), you can add a constructor that takes the values of the initializer list as arguments and use those to initialize your data members.

Adding the following constructor will suffice, in the code you have shown:

```cpp
    TestStruct(bool bval, TestEnum eval) : test_bool{ bval }, test_enum{ eval } {}
```

Alternatively, you can remove the `TestStruct() = delete;` line, unless there is a specific reason you want to remove the default constructor.

---

<sup>†</sup> Note that, although your GCC-4.8.5 isn't one of them, any compilers conforming to the C++20 (or later) Standard will also not allow this aggregate initialization; adding the suggested constructor will work on those, as well as on your GCC (if that is set to use C++11).

Comment: He's complaining that it doesn't compile on the ancient compiler that's default on RHEL 7.  It is C++03 by default, but supports C++11 plus a few additional features if you use a command-line argument as he does in the example posted.  It is certainly not using newer C++20 rules!

Comment: @JDługosz Even with the C++11 Standard (as in the first of the Compiler Explorer links given in the comment by G.M.), adding that constructor solves the problem. My note about C++20 is merely an expansion on "compilers that don't support/allow..." I added it for any future readers who may encounter this issue when porting similar code to compilers that ***do*** use the C++20 Standard.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was surprised that the deleted constructor was the issue, since the cppreference page says `no user-provided constructors (explicitly defaulted or deleted constructors are allowed) (since C++11)`. Adding the explicit constructor and removing all uses of aggregate initialization worked.

Comment: @Phydeaux I am also a bit confused by that statement on cppreference. I checked a draft C++17 Standard I have and it it less specific. I guess what's upsetting (some) compilers is that there is **no** available constructor if you delete the default but don't provide an alternative; but, that's mostly speculation.